# Running VBA code only after a specific input value was entered

Tags: vba, excel, events

I'm trying to do a macro that whenever someone types "New Hire" in the range `D20:D50`, it would call a macro. I know I can do it with an `If` but the problem is that there are to many cells and a lot of code. I need to use `ByVal Target As Range`, because whenever they type the word I want to call a macro.

```
If Target.Address = "$D$20" Then

        If Range("D20").Value = "New Hire" Then

            MsgBox "Please Fulfill the New Hire(s) Information in the following New Hire Sheet" & vbNewLine & "Important Note" & vbNewLine & "Include the New Employee's ID and Bank documentation with Account Number information"
            Call NewHireForm    

ElseIf Target.Address = "$D$21" Then

        If Range("D21").Value = "New Hire" Then

            MsgBox "Please Fulfill the New Hire(s) Information in the following New Hire Sheet" & vbNewLine & "Important Note" & vbNewLine & "Include the New Employee's ID and Bank documentation with Account Number information"
            Call NewHireForm
```

You see, it's not simplified. Is there a way to whenever they type "New Hire" in range `D20` to `D50` to make the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given code in your Worksheet module. The main line here is `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D20:D50")) Is Nothing Then`. It says that the code will be executed only if values within `Range("D20:D50")` were changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errH
    Dim cell As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D20:D50")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Target
            If cell.Value = "New Hire" Then
                MsgBox "Please Fulfill the New Hire(s) Information in the following New Hire Sheet" & vbNewLine & "Important Note" & vbNewLine & "Include the New Employee's ID and Bank documentation with Account Number information"
                Call NewHireForm
            End If
        Next
    End If
errH:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You need to open your VBE, in your Project Window choose the worksheet that you need and paste the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're amazing, with this code I can use as base for anything. Regards!

Comment: I have another question, let's imagine the person who is filling the sheet, doesn't want to type cell by cell, and he decides to do a copy dropdown to the following 10 cell. In my code, instead of calling a macro, I highlight the right cell in yellow, how can you highlight the right cells after he did a copy and paste?

Comment: I made one small change - `If Target.Value = "New Hire" Then` became `If cell.Value = "New Hire" Then`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would be pretty simple. Try inserting the following line: `cell.Interior.Color = 65535`. The code above also works when users choose pasting several cells at once.